# set umask per user

Tags: sftp, pam

It's possible to force any ssh type connection to have a umask of 0777 using pam. This is what I have:

```
# /etc/pam.d/ssh
sesssion required pam_umask.so umask=0777
```

I want to do this only for a certain user/group. I've read that pam_umask is capable of this, but I've not been able to figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work for non-login sessions, but I've always taken the approach of modifying the user's `.bash{rc,profile}`.  Failing that, you can do the opposite: set umask to `0777` with pam, and then change that further for login sessions in global `bashrc`.

That said, a umask of `0777` is alarming.  You realize this means your users will create files with a mode of `0000`--that is, no access for **anyone**--right?

Comment: Yup, I realize that. It has to be for non-login sessions. I want the default umask for login sessions.